# Windshield Wiper Over An Airplane's Curved Windshield

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, objects, axis

so I'm running into a small problem when trying to make the wiper move along the glass, but this one is curved. The windshield is pretty curved and the wiper doesn't really need a lot of detail (picture 1) because it is a big airplane.

[image: Picture 1. Wiper at starting position]

But I think it would look nice that the wiper moved along the curved windshield. Also I cannot bend the wiper because the curvature of the glass is uneven, so the wiper gets stuck inside the glass in some parts.

[image: Picture 2. Wiper after rotation]

Is there a way I can achieve this movement without modifying the wiper too much? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try bend Wiper by curve object and curve object shrinkwrap on Glass.
It depence on what wiper vertices you want to bend you can limited it by Vertex Group.

[image]
Quick example is not perfect "wiper" rotates on its Z axis. I will have to check it later.

[image]

Or Bendi Bones could work in similar way as well.

---

### Add-on Wiper

for 2.79 (Luca Rood) https://gumroad.com/l/wiper

Comment: nice, I guess a Surface Deform should work as well